# SwiftUI - How to avoid to refresh a List when a state var from the same struct is modified

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a main view which contains a body with a TabView and each tab shows a different list. Also, I have declared at the top of the main class, a state var just for control if I have to show a modal-like view or not.

The problem is that when I change the value of that state var, all body of the main view is redrawn with an animation. This is not a desired behaviour because I am not changing the data associated with the list updating that var.

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @State private var selection = 0
    @State var modalShown = false //This is the problematic var that makes a list to be updated with an animation

    @EnvironmentObject var filters: UserFilters
    @EnvironmentObject var filtersViewController: FiltersViewController

    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.03921568627, green: 0.03921568627, blue: 0.03921568627, alpha: 1)
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.03921568627, green: 0.03921568627, blue: 0.03921568627, alpha: 1)
    }

    var body: some View {
        return ZStack {
            TabView(selection: $selection){
                IncidencesView(modalShown: $modalShown) //A view that contains a list that is being refreshing
```

At least, is there a way to avoid the list updating animation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> At least, is there a way to avoid the list updating animation?

The provided code snapshot is not testable, so just on-the-fly... try the following

```
IncidencesView(modalShown: $modalShown.animation(nil))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

Make your view, I believe in this case `IncidencesView`, conform to `Equatable`. 
That will require you to overload the == operator and tell SwiftUI exactly under what circumstances the view has changed and when it hasn't changed.

Once you do that, in `HomeView` modify `IncidencesView` with the `.equitable()` view modifier, to tell it's parent `HomeView` to check if `IncidencesView` is still equal to it's old self when there is a change of state. If it is still equal to it's old self, don't redraw.

Now even if `selection` changes, SwiftUI, will check if the current `IncidencesView` is still equal to the version under this new condition. It will see it is (because `selection` likely doesn't influence the == function result), and so a new version of the view won't be recreated and drawn.

See this excellent article: https://swiftui-lab.com/equatableview/